# Не получается объединить значения span'ов в другой span

Tags: javascript

У неограниченного числа span'ов одинаковые классы basket_item_sum, нужно чтобы данные входили внутрь span'a с классом basket_sum. Пытался сделать через document.getElementsByClass, но ничего не вышло.

Comment: Сюда страшно смотреть, ибо в перемешку с php кодом https://pastebin.com/1uEBVipt

Comment: все равно это огрызок. разместите полностью

Comment: какой результат ожидается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let span = document.querySelectorAll(".basket");
let ocum = [];

span.forEach(function(sp) {
  ocum.push(+sp.textContent);
})

result.innerHTML = " = " + ocum.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; color: blue; font-size: 24px;">
  <span class="basket">23</span>
  <span class="basket">11</span>
  <span class="basket">2</span>
  <span class="basket">67</span>
  <span class="basket">34</span>
  <span class="basket">112</span>
</div>

<span id="result" style="color: red; font-size: 24px;"></span>
```